# No whitespace when Importing PDF files made with LaTeX?

Tags: bugs, import, pdf-format, latex

This was done using miktex on Windows:

```
file = CreateFile[]; WriteString[file, "\\documentclass{scrartcl}
 \\usepackage{amsmath}
 \\usepackage{amsfonts}
 \\usepackage{tabto}
 \\usepackage{enumerate}
 \\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \\usepackage{lmodern}
 \\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
 \\usepackage{tabularx}
 \\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]\
{geometry}
 \\usepackage{nccmath}
 \\usepackage{xcolor}
 \\usepackage{graphics}
 
 \\title{Literally No Spacing whatsoever}
 \\begin{document}
 \\maketitle
 \\end{section}
 \\end{document}"];
FilePrint[file];

RunProcess[{"pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", 
   AbsoluteFileName[file]}];
Import["C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\" <> FileNameTake[file] <> 
  ".pdf", {"PDF", "Pages"}]
```

The above produces the following:

[image: pdfwithnospacing]

However, Adobe Acrobat renders the file like this:

[image: lol]

Is this a bug?

How do I import a PDF in *Mathematica* with the whitespaces?

Comment: If you want to import LaTeX-generated PDFs, I recommend you use [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX/) . It works around such problems by expanding fonts to outlines with Ghostscript. You can check its source code for the details.

Comment: @Szabolcs that works if you want to import TeX fragments, but I want the whole page, in this case.. I guess I can go read it's source.

Comment: It's a simple call to Ghostscript to post-process the LaTeX-produced PDF file. You can see the command line arguments here: https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX/blob/master/MaTeX/MaTeX.m#L494 That's basically all you need.

Comment: It seems that LaTeX-generated PDFs can be "fixed" by passing them through [Poppler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615998/590388)'s `pdftocairo`. Please try: `pdftocairo -level2 -pdf pdflatex_output.pdf pdflatex_output_fixed.pdf`.